# SQLSyntaxError even when using Prepared Statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, syntax-error

I am constantly getting an SQL Syntax Error but I can't understand where I am going wrong with this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Weights"
            + " (ID, W1, W2, W3, W4, W5)"
            + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

     PreparedStatement statement = mysqlConnect.connect().prepareStatement( sql );
     statement.setString(1, String.valueOf( col-1 ) );
     statement.setDouble(2, weights[row][c]);
     statement.setDouble(3, weights[row][c]);
     statement.setDouble(4, weights[row][c]);
     statement.setDouble(5, weights[row][c]);
     statement.setDouble(6, weights[row][c]);
     statement.execute(sql);
```

Comment: To summarize the linked duplicate: you need to use `statement.execute()` (or `statement.executeUpdate()`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql syntax is off, the statement for inserts is.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES(v1, v2, ...)
```

You are basicly missing a parenthese, changed to following.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Weights"
        + "(ID, W1, W2, W3, W4, W5)"
        + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't see it for looking at it! I have fixed this, but I am still getting the error :(

Comment: The SQL statement should be fine Any other error message?

Comment: Nope its the same error on the same line again!

Comment: try to add the values like this ("+ weights[row][c]+" ...) and print the sql statement and see hwo it looks and post it here:)

Comment: All parentheses are balanced in the question. This is not the problem.

Comment: Yes,  because he edited his question.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that, sorry. I have now closed it with a duplicate that show how to fix the (new) problem (using the wrong `execute` method).